# Understanding Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, loops, array.prototype.map

I was going through the Javascript map function, and stuck at the loop syntax. It is difficult to figure out the **o placed after comma**. Can anybody help me figure it out. Also what is the terminating condition for loop ?

```
Array.prototype.mymap = function (callback) {
  var obj = Object(this);

  if (obj.length === 0) return null;
  if (typeof(callback) === 'undefined') return null;

  for (var i = 0, o; o = obj[i]; i++) {
    obj[i] = callback(o);
  }

  return obj;
};
```

Comment: it just declares another variable named `o`

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Hi, AlgoreRythm, I am not seeing any error, I just want to understand that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, o; o = obj[i]; i++) {
    obj[i] = callback(o);
}
```

This is the same as:

```
var i = 0,
    o;

while (o = obj[i]) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

Which means, it declares the variable `o`, which is initially set to `undefined`. During each loop iteration, `obj[i]` is assigned to `o`. When `obj[i]` results in `undefined` (because `i` is beyond the length of the array), the expression `o = obj[i]` results in `undefined`, which terminates the loop.

Actually, this loop implementation has a bug: it terminates whenever any array value is *falsey*; which is probably not desired.

Comment: Thanks torazburo and deceze, Got it now :)